# Java security warnings while loading applets

Tags: java, security

I have some issues while using some applet in my application. It's showing that i have untrusted applet, that my jar files are not allowed to be run, showing that they are also using an old version of java (I'm using java 1.7).

Do you have any solution, like maybe using a third-pary certificate ?

Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you check your java version from command prompt? Use java -version command. It might possible you have different java version and you are referring to older version.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I am getting pop up bloker. Whenever applet loading to the client system user getting pop issue.how to control. How to disable javasecurity pop permanently. Pls advice.

Comment: It's basically browser setting. What browser you are using?

Comment: I checked all browsers, same issue still exists. So pls provide. Solution for this issue. Present in my system I am using ie11. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps. You will see more details [here](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/jcp_security.xml)

Setting the Security levels through the Java Control Panel

1. In the Java Control Panel, click on the Security tab.
2. Select the desired Security level.
3. Click Apply.
4. Click OK to save changes made to the Java Control Panel.

[image]

**Security levels in the Java Control Panel**

**Very High**

This is the most restrictive security level setting. All the applications that are signed with a valid certificate and include the Permissions attribute in the manifest for the main JAR file are allowed to run with security prompts. All other applications are blocked.

**High**

This is the minimum recommended (and default) security level setting. Applications that are signed with a valid or expired certificate and include the Permissions attribute in the manifest for the main JAR file are allowed to run with security prompts. Applications are also allowed to run with security prompts when the revocation status of the certificate cannot be checked. All other applications are blocked.

**Medium (removed from Java 8 Update 20 and later versions)**

Only unsigned applications that request all permissions are blocked. All other applications are allowed to run with security prompts. Selecting the Medium security level is not recommended and will make your computer more vulnerable should you run a malicious application.

Comment: The above solutions is not working properly so ps provide solution. If I set high and very high setting in java control panel. I am getting more error message.

Comment: Follow this and see if this helps 1. Open Control Panel and launch the Java applet. If you don't see it, switch to Classic View (in XP) or small icons (in Windows 7 or Vista).
2. Click the Advanced tab and expand the item titled Default Java for browsers.
3. Un-check the boxes for Microsoft Internet Explorer and for Mozilla family. You may need to click the item and press spacebar in order to clear the checkmarks.
4. Click OK and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

The part of "Resolution" in that website said.

"Since the issue is being reported by the Java software or the Java plugin in the browser, there is nothing we can do to directly resolve the issue.

There are several workarounds possible, depending on how the site deals with browser security issues.

The most secure approach is to allow the applet to be run each time you are prompted.

If using Internet Explorer, click the [Run] button on the security warning popup window.
If using Firefox, two actions may be needed.  First if the warning "This connection is untrusted" is displayed, click the "I Understand the Risks""